# Data Extraction using Regex

Tags: regex, data-extraction

I have data in a text file "file.txt"

> Recipes & Menus
>   Expert Advice
>   *Ingredients*
>   Holidays & Events
>   Community
>   Video
>   SUMMER COOKING
>   Lentil and Brown Rice Soup
>   Gourmet January 1991
>   3.5/4
>   reviews (83)
>   90%
>   make it again
>   Some soups genuinely do inspire a devotion akin to love, and this is one of
>  them. In the cold of winter, when Gourmet editors ponder the matter of what soup
>  
>   Cook
>   Reviews (83)
>   YIELD: Makes about 14 cups, serving 6 to 8
>   **Ingredients**
>   5 cups chicken broth
>   1 1/2 cups lentils, picked over and rinsed
>   1 cup brown rice
>   a 32- to 35-ounce can tomatoes, drained, reserving the juice, and chopped
>   3 carrots, halved lengthwise and cut crosswise into 1/4-inch pieces
>   1 onion, chopped
>   1 stalk of celery, chopped
>   3 garlic cloves, minced
>   1/2 teaspoon crumbled dried basil
>   1/2 teaspoon crumbled dried orégano
>   1/4 teaspoon crumbled dried thyme
>   1 bay leaf
>   1/2 cup minced fresh parsley leaves
>   2 tablespoons cider vinegar, or to taste
>   **Preparation**
>   In a heavy kettle combine the broth, 3 cups water, the lentils, the rice, the tomatoes with the reserved juice,

I want to extract the data between **Ingredients** and **Preparation**.
I had written the following regex for it :-

```
(?s).*?Ingredients(.*?)Preparation.*
```

But it's extracting the data between the *Ingredients* in italics on 3rd line of
 file.txt and **Preparation** but not between the data between **Ingredients** and **Preparation**
What changes in my regex code should I do to resolve this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exact regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your first `.*` greedy. It will eat all `Ingredients` up until the last one before `Preparation`:

```
(?s).*Ingredients(.*?)Preparation.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mQ5eK5/1

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a lazy quantifier `.*?` with the second `.*`:

```
(?s).*\bIngredients\b(.*?)\bPreparation\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI6wJ6/3)

Or you can make use of a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) and then you do not need the first `.*`:

```
(?s)\bIngredients\b(?:(?!\b(?:Ingredients|Preparation)\b).)*\bPreparation\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI6wJ6/1)

Comment: Could you please let me know what is wrong with my answer? The one you switched to does not check word boundaries and can match `Preparations` that can be before the `Preparation`, and you will get a wrong submatch.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?s).*?[*]{2}Ingredients[*]{2}(.*?)[*]{2}Preparation[*]{2}.*
```

`[*]{2}`tell the regex you want one of the chars in the list (here a single `*`) excatly twice `{2}`.

I prefer using character classes than escaping, I found them more readable than this:

```
(?s).*?\*{2}Ingredients\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}Preparation\*{2}.*
```

and depending on the language you're using you may have to escape the backslash too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead that checks that each line is not `Ingredients`. In this way you limit the number of tests to only the start of lines (instead of testing each characters):

```
(?m)^Ingredients\R((?:(?!Ingredients$).*\R)+?)Preparation$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV4hV4/1)

pattern details:

```
(?m)             # switch on the multiline mode (^ and $ match the limit of the line)
^Ingredients\R   # "Ingredients" at the start of the line followed by a new line
(   # capture group 1
    (?:          # open a non-capturing group
        (?!Ingredients$) # negative lookahead to check that the line is not "Ingredients"
        .*\R             # the line
    )+? # repeat until "Preparation"
)
Preparation$
```

Note: since you didn't say what regex engine you use, it is possible that `\R` is not supported. In this case, replace it with `\r?\n`.